# How to sort queried row columns values then display them on HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table with a user ID, and rewards. This user can collect different rewards, thus getting different total values for each reward. See below:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| uid | rw1 | rw2 | rw3 | rw4 |
|  5  |  2  |  6  |  9  |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I am querying them from my database table. How can I order these values by largest to smallest? I have a div on my user page that shows all of their rewards, but I want the highest accounted reward to be displayed first on the webpage. How can I do this? Not to make it more difficult, but these numbers are part of a larger block element that has icons and names. Thanks!
PHP ECHO to HTML

```
$html = '';
$html .='
<div class="reward container id="'.$uid.'">
    <div class="reward-block>
        <div class="reward_icon">
            <img>
        </div>
        <h4>'.rw3.'</div>
    <div>
    <div class="reward-block>
        <div class="reward_icon">
            <img>
        </div>
        <h4>'.rw2.'</div>
    <div>
    <div class="reward-block>
        <div class="reward_icon">
            <img>
        </div>
        <h4>'.rw1.'</div>
    <div>
    <div class="reward-block>
        <div class="reward_icon">
            <img>
        </div>
        <h4>'.rw4.'</div>
    <div>
</div>
';

echo $html;
//echo to HTML
```

Comment: can you give us an example what you want as result?

Comment: you mean: SELECT * FROM rewards ORDER BY rw1 DESC, rw2 DESC, rw3 DESC, rw4 DESC

Comment: basically I want the result on the HTML to be RW3, RW2, RW1, RW4, with their respective parent divs of course

Comment: i just updated the question

Comment: We're here to help you sort out issues with your existing code. However, we're not here to do your job for you.
Post what you've tried, example data, expected result and what you're currently getting. You can read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort with the `ORDER BY`

Example:

```
SELECT
    city,
    first_name,
    last_name
FROM
    sales.customers
ORDER BY
    city DESC,
    first_name ASC;
```

In the example above we are sorting based on the `city` value in a descending order and the `first_name` in a ascending order.

For your case it would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY
   RW3 DESC,
   RW2 DESC,
   RW1 DESC,
   RW4 DESC
```

Comment: what if you dont know which one is the highest value? the amount of rewards will vary based on the user

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mark hope that you are getting lots of fun programming. Let me help you with this one. If you copy and paste this in a `file.php` and put it in your `xampp` `htdocs` with the name of `index.php` you will be set up in less than 5 minutes.

```
    <?php

    //

    /*FIRST YOU NEED TO CONNECT TO YOUR DATABASE
    YOU WILL NEED TO REPLACE SOME VALUES, [dbname], [user], [pass] if you are using xampp localhost will be fine if you are using another server manager then use the name that you use to access your data base.*/

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost;charset=utf8", 'user', 'pass');

    /*
        In the line below we do 2 things first we create a variable called $stm (is a short for statement) and then we use a PDO method (is just a function inside a class and a class is a collection of usefull functions).
        and second we place a query inside the method between quotes '' or ""
    */

//Sorting is done with the ORDER BY followed by the rows you want to sort.
//ASC is for ascending and DESC is for descending sorting

    $stm = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM  table ORDER BY rw1, rw2, rw3, rw4 ASC');
    /*THEN WE WILL EXECUTE THE MYSQL QUERY TO GET THE RESULTS*/
    $stm->execute();

    //PACK THIS IN A NICE ARRAY
    $results = (array)$stm->fetchAll();

    ?>

        <!-- AFTER THE ?> THIS SECTION IS HTML -->
        <!-- NOW WE TAKE THE ARRAY AND ONE BY ONE WE CAN PRINT IT IN A UL OR A DIV JUST CHANGE THE HTML TAGS AND YOU'LL BE SET, IF YOU JUST PAST THIS IN A PHP AND REPLACE THE INFO YOU SHOULD GET EVERYTHING UP AND RUNNING IN LES THAN 3 MINUTES-->
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($results as $result): //this is php embedded inline ?>

                    <li>
                        <!-- THEN HERE WE PRINT THEM ONE BY ONE -->
                        <?php echo "{$result['uid']}, {$result['rw1']}, {$result['rw1']}, {$result['rw2']}, {$result['rw3']}, {$result['rw4']}"; //this is php embedded inline?>

                    </li>

            <?php endforeach; //this is php embedded inline ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: thanks, i already know how to fetch data from the database, the problem is sorting it by the column values, greatest to smallest